# Melhor forma de se relacionar duas tabelas

Tags: sql, relacionamento

Eu tenho duas tabelas (`groups` e `roles`):

Tabela `groups`:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | color | role |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

Tabela `roles`:

```
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| id | name | alias | description |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
```

A pergunta é: qual o melhor jeito de se relacionar as duas tabelas, de modo que:

- Cada grupo (`group`) pode ter uma ou mais funções (`role`s);
- Cada função (`role`) pode estar ligada a vários grupos ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta de @MurilloGoulart está correta mas apenas para ser mais completo...

*"Em análise de sistemas, um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos (também abreviado como N para N ou N:N) é um tipo de cardinalidade que refere-se ao relacionamento entre duas entidades A e L, no qual A pode conter uma instância pai para a qual existem muitas instâncias filhas em L e vice versa.*

*Por exemplo, pensando-se em A como Autores e L como Livros, um Autor pode escrever vários Livros e um Livro pode ser escrito por vários Autores.*

*Em um sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados relacional, tais relacionamentos são normalmente implementados por meio de uma tabela associativa (também conhecida como tabela de junção ou tabela de referência cruzada). Por exemplo, uma tabela AL possuindo dois relacionamentos um-para-muitos A → AL e L → AL. Neste caso, a chave primária lógica para AL é formada de duas chaves estrangeiras (isto é, cópias das chaves primárias de A e L)."* [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muitos-para-muitos_(modelagem_de_dados))

Basicamente, em relações de muitos para muitos, ou N para N, é criado um terceira tabela onde fica guardado as chaves estrangeiras, ou Foreign Keys (FK) das duas outras tabelas, mas não é só isso, a tabela gerada, assim como as demais possui uma chave única (chave primária)

**Quando a relação não pode ter repetição da combinação das chaves estrangeiras**

Por exemplo, um livro pode ter vários autores, que podem ter vários livros mas nunca vai haver um mesmo autor referenciando o mesmo livro duas vezes, nesses casos o índice pode ser formado pela união das colunas, o comando pode mudar de acordo com a linguagem SQL

**Em casos que pode haver duas linhas com a mesma combinação de FK**

Um exemplo prático (que me foi ensinado), é uma locadora onde possui uma tabela filmes e uma tabela clientes, onde um cliente pode alugar um ou mais filmes e os filmes pode ser alugados por um ou mais clientes, lembrando que uma locadora tem várias unidades do mesmo filme

É criado uma outra coluna que será a chave primária para essa tabela/relação:

```
   filmes_clientes      filmes     clientes
 +-----+-----+-----+    +-----+    +-----+
 | pk  | fk1 | fk2 |    | pk1 |    | pk2 |
 +-----+-----+-----+    +-----+    +-----+
 |  0  |  1  |  0  |    |  0  |    |  0  |
 +-----+-----+-----+    +-----+    +-----+
 |  1  |  1  |  0  |    |  1  |    |  1  |
 +-----+-----+-----+    +-----+    +-----+
```

**Outra opção é usar outra coluna que guarde a data**

Se por algum motivo nessa relação vai ser guardado também a data em que ela ocorreu pode usar a mesma para criar a chave única, por exemplo:

```
           filmes_clientes                filmes     clientes
 +-----+-----+-----------------------+    +-----+    +-----+
 | fk1 | fk2 |          data         |    | pk1 |    | pk2 |
 +-----+-----+-----------------------+    +-----+    +-----+
 |  1  |  0  |  2018-04-30 16:05:00  |    |  0  |    |  0  |
 +-----+-----+-----------------------+    +-----+    +-----+
 |  1  |  0  |  2018-04-30 16:05:01  |    |  1  |    |  1  |
 +-----+-----+-----------------------+    +-----+    +-----+
```

Mas deve-se tomar cuidado nesses casos, imagine uma locadora que possui filiais onde uma pessoa alugou um filme com o seu usuário e o seu companheiro(a) alugou o mesmo filme com o mesmo usuário ao mesmo tempo, difícil de acontecer (ainda mais numa locadora) mas pode acontecer e gerar conflito. Claro que você também pode colocar além da data, a filial onde o filme foi alugado, mas ai já vai duas colunas extras que talvez nem sejam usadas, apenas estão ali para não haver duplicidade, por isso uma PK na tabela originada da relação N:N

Answer (score 4):

Precisa ter uma tabela intermediária para fazer relacionamento N:N:

Tabela `groups_roles`:

```
+----------+---------+
| id_group | id_role |
+----------+---------+
```