# Android - Como criar e combinar duas tabelas dentro de uma lista de tabelas SQLite no Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu estou criando um aplicativo para monitorar os paramentros de um aquário usando o esquema a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário pode monitorar quantos aquários quiser, porém toda vez que ele adicionar um novo aquário, essas duas tabelas deveram ser criadas e estar sempre linkadas.

E os parametros da agua precisam ser mantidos ao longo do tempo, pois eu vou usa-los em um gráfico. Mostrando as alterações ao longo do tempo. Por exemplo, um grafico que mostra a quantidade de sal ao longo de uma semana.

Ai que entra minha dúvida, pois estou começando a programar a pouco tempo.

1. Como eu posso criar e juntar essas duas tabelas, todas vez que o usuário adicionar um novo aquário?
2. E como eu faria para não misturar com outras tabelas, se o usuário tivesse adicionado 5 aquários no app?

Eu andei pesquisando e vi que chave estrangeira pode ser útil no meu caso, mas não sei se isso me ajudaria, nem como prosseguir.

Nota: Apenas um esclarecimento. Eu não preciso do be-a-bá, tenho um conhecimento básico no Android. Sei manusear uma db, fazer operações CRUD, Cursor, ContentProvider, etc. Mas estou perdido neste caso. Não gostaria de passar a impressão de preguiço. Apenas não noção de qual caminho seguir, nem de quais ferramentas usar.

Comment: Por que duas tabelas diferentes? Um aquário pode ter mais de um parâmetro e/ou vice-versa? Acredito que não, e a melhor solução seria unir ambas as tabelas. Se quiser pode pesquisar mais sobre cardinalidade nas relações entre tabelas

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas vou tentar esclarecer melhor. Duas tabelas por que as informações do aquario em si não mudam, mas os parametros sim. Por exemplo, a salinidade da agua muda ao decorrer do tempo, o pH da agua pode mudar muito rapidamente ao decorrer dos das horas, ou dos dias. O usuário pode muito bem querer registrar os parametros várias vezes durando o dia, ou a semana. Dai eu tirei a ideia de ter uma tabela exclusivamente para os paramentros. Mas se ainda tiver como fazer em uma tabela só, como seria? Eu quero manter dos dados ao longo do tempo para exibir um grafico

Comment: Então a relação entre aquário e parâmetros e de 1:N, porque você quer manter sempre o registro de parâmetros anteriores, não seria interessante adicionar um campo data?

Comment: Quero manter o registro dos dados para exibir um gráfico. Penso fazer isso usando data e hora. Acho que agora consegui explicar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar uma nova coluna na tabela parâmetros, essa coluna será uma chave estrangeira que referenciara a chave primária da tabela aquário (aquarioId):

```
CREATE TABLE parametros(
    //...
    aquerioId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(aquerioId) REFERENCES aquerio(aquerioId)
);
```

Sempre que adicionar uma nova linha na tabela parâmetros, deve adicionar o id do aquário que aquela linha se refere

Observe que a chave estrangeira deve ser do mesmo tipo de dado e tamanho que a chave primária que ela se refere

Comment: Entendi. Então nesse caso eu poderia ter várias tabelas aquario e apenas uma com os parametros, certo? Por exemplo, isso se daria se o usuário tivesse 5 aquarios. Certo?

Comment: Mais ou menos, sim o usuário pode ter vários aquários, mas da forma como eu indiquei cada aquário pode ter vários parâmetros, eu entendi que era isso que queria, muitos parâmetros para cada aquário, entendi certo?

Comment: Sim. Está, mas só outra duvida ainda restou. Cada vez que o usuário quiser adicionar um novo aquario, eu vou ter que criar duas novas tabelas? Ou eu posso ficar criando o apenas a tabela aquario e ficar usando somente 1 tabela parametro para ficar salvando os parametros de todos os aquarios?

Comment: Não, nesse modelo você não precisa adicionar um parâmetro sempre que adicionar um aquário, pode adicionar só os aquários e quando o usuário quiser adiciona os parâmetros, porém um parâmetro não pode ser vinculado a mais de um aquário, se quiser isso precisará de uma outra tabela, [nessa reaposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295192/melhor-forma-de-se-relacionar-duas-tabelas/295220#295220) eu explico melhor isso. Porém, pelo que entendi do projeto, sugiro que continue da forma que está, duas tabelas um aquário tem nenhum ou muitos parâmetros que são de apenas um aquários